# Next JS responsive image with custom size

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-images

I'm trying to implement an image grid like in AirBnB with Next JS. so I'm Using Next Image with responsive layout. but i wanted to make the image square. meaning the height and width should be the same. but when in responsive layout the image is set with it's original size. i even tried to make the object fit cover.

```
<div className="relative flex flex-col -z-10">
      <Image
        src={"/profile.webp"}
        layout="responsive"
        objectFit="cover"
        height={100}
        width={100}
      />
    </div>
```

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the code that worked for me, if anyone looks for this maybe it will be useful.

```
      <div className="w-full relative pt-[100%]">
        <Image
          src="/profile.webp"
          alt="profile"
          objectFit="cover"
          fill
          className="w-full h-full top-0 left-0 object-cover rounded-2xl"
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. There aren't many resources for using the Image component in Next 13. 

P.S. I got a weird behavior by `object-cover`, for my design, `object-contain` had the best behavior (shrinking while keeping the same aspect ratio).

Comment: The problem with using "fill" is that the next Image component doesn't optimize images anymore. So if your image is big and heavy, it would not change it's size or quality.

Comment: ```pt-[50%]``` is working for me the best. thanks anyway....

Comment: what about list of images , say 3 imager per row in desktop, 1 image 1 row for mobile?

Comment: @JeffBootsholz I think what you're asking is for desktop 3 images per row and for mobile 1 image per row, right? if that's the case you can use a grid and set col-span. like in tailwind you can do `grid grid-flow-row-dense grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-5 2xl:grid-cols-6` this will set 1 image for mobile, 2 images for tablet and so on. so play with this and see what fits your design.

Answer (score 5):

Use this method for the NextJS 13 image:
Enable **experimental** feature image by adding this to the **next.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
experimental: {
    images: {
        allowFutureImage: true
    }
  },
}
```

By enabling this, you can now add style or classes directly to the image components.

```js
<Image
    src={data.image}
    width="0"
    height="0"
    sizes="100vw"
    className="w-full h-auto"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

with MUI

```html
       <Box
          sx={{
            width: { md: '161px', xs: '120px' },
            height: { md: '28px', xs: '21px' },
            position: 'relative'
          }}>
          <Image
            src={'/assets/logo.svg'}
            alt='logo'
            layout='fill'
            objectFit='cover'
          />
        </Box>
```